# What ports does Clash of Clans use?

Tags: clash-of-clans, networking

The wifi at my office blocks Clash of Clans. They're usually pretty open to unblocking applications but I need to know what ports CoC uses.

Comment: Oh the irony of asking how to get around the Stack Exchange corporate firewall to play games while working at Stack Exchange.

Comment: Not getting around. Just figuring what I need to ask IT to open up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Clash of Clans port is currently `9339` and the port `80` is used for the ads and also `service.supercell.net.`

[Source](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/699-Firewall-ports-and-addresses)